# Error en creación de una alcancía

Tags: c++

Tengo el código

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    class Alcancia

   {

   public:

   Alcancia(int M20, int M50, int M100, int M200, int M500);

   virtual ~Alcancia();

   void agregarMoneda20();

   void agregarMoneda50();

    void agregarMoneda100();

    void agregarMoneda200();

    void agregarMoneda500();

    void settotalDinero(int Mo20, int Mo50, int Mo100, int Mo200, int Mo500);

    int gettotalDinero();
    void setcantidadMonedas20(int CM20);
    int getcantidadMonedas20();
    void setcantidadMonedas50(int CM50);
    int getcantidadMonedas50();
    void setcantidadMonedas100(int CM100);
    int getcantidadMonedas100();
    void setcantidadMonedas200(int CM200);
    int getcantidadMonedas200();
    void setcantidadMonedas500(int CM500);
    int getcantidadMonedas500();
    void vaciarAlcancia();

protected:

private:
    int cantidadDineroAhorrado;
    int cantidadMonedas20;
    int cantidadMonedas50;
    int cantidadMonedas100;
    int cantidadMonedas200;
    int cantidadMonedas500;
    };

    Alcancia::Alcancia(int M20, int M50, int M100, int M200, int M500)
    {
    setcantidadMonedas20(M20);
    setcantidadMonedas50(M50);
    setcantidadMonedas100(M100);
    setcantidadMonedas200(M200);
    setcantidadMonedas500(M500);
    }

    Alcancia::~Alcancia()
    {
     //dtor
    }

    void Alcancia::setcantidadMonedas20(int CM20)
    {
    cantidadMonedas20 = cantidadMonedas20 + CM20;
    }

    int Alcancia::getcantidadMonedas20()
    {
    return cantidadMonedas20;
    }
    void Alcancia::agregarMoneda20()
    {
    setcantidadMonedas20(1);
    }

    void Alcancia::setcantidadMonedas50(int CM50)
    {
    cantidadMonedas50 = cantidadMonedas50 + CM50;
    }

    int Alcancia::getcantidadMonedas50()
    {
    return cantidadMonedas50;
    }
    void Alcancia::agregarMoneda50()
    {
    setcantidadMonedas50(1);
    }

    void Alcancia::setcantidadMonedas100(int CM100)
    {
    cantidadMonedas100 = cantidadMonedas100 + CM100;
    }

    int Alcancia::getcantidadMonedas100()
    {
    return cantidadMonedas100;
    }

    void Alcancia::setcantidadMonedas200(int CM200)
{
    cantidadMonedas200 = cantidadMonedas200 + CM200;
}

int Alcancia::getcantidadMonedas200()
{
    return cantidadMonedas200;
}

void Alcancia::setcantidadMonedas500(int CM500)
{
    cantidadMonedas500 = cantidadMonedas500 + CM500;
}

int Alcancia::getcantidadMonedas500()
{
    return cantidadMonedas500;
}

void Alcancia::agregarMoneda100()
{
    setcantidadMonedas100(1);
}

void Alcancia::agregarMoneda200()
{
    setcantidadMonedas200(1);
}

void Alcancia::agregarMoneda500()
{
    setcantidadMonedas100(1);
}

void Alcancia::settotalDinero(int Mo20, int Mo50, int Mo100, int Mo200, int Mo500)
{
    cantidadDineroAhorrado = ((Mo20 * 20) + (Mo50 * 50) + (Mo100 * 100) + (Mo200 * 200) + (Mo500 * 500));
}

int Alcancia::gettotalDinero()
{
    return cantidadDineroAhorrado;
}

void Alcancia::vaciarAlcancia()
{

    settotalDinero(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    setcantidadMonedas20(getcantidadMonedas20() * -1);
    setcantidadMonedas50(getcantidadMonedas50() * -1);
    setcantidadMonedas100(getcantidadMonedas100() * -1);
    setcantidadMonedas200(getcantidadMonedas200() * -1);
    setcantidadMonedas500(getcantidadMonedas500() * -1);
}


int main()
{
    int opcion;
    Alcancia alcancia1 = Alcancia(0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    cout<<"ALCANCIA DE CERDITO"<<endl;
    cout<<"¿Que desea hacer?"<<endl;
    cout<<"1. Agregar una moneda de $20"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Agregar una moneda de $50"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. Agregar una moneda de $100"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. Agregar una moneda de $200"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. Agregar una moneda de $500"<<endl;
    cout<<"6. Vaciar la alcancia"<<endl;
    cout<<"7. Cantidad de monedas de $20"<<endl;
    cout<<"8. Cantidad de monedas de $50"<<endl;
    cout<<"9. Cantidad de monedas de $100"<<endl;
    cout<<"10. Cantidad de monedas de $200"<<endl;
    cout<<"11. Cantidad de monedas de $500"<<endl;
    cout<<"12. Total dinero ahorrado"<<endl;
    cin>>opcion;
    if (opcion == 1)
    alcancia1.agregarMoneda20();
    if (opcion == 2)
    alcancia1.agregarMoneda50();
    if (opcion == 3)
    alcancia1.agregarMoneda100();
    if (opcion == 4)
    alcancia1.agregarMoneda200();
    if (opcion == 5)
    alcancia1.agregarMoneda500();
    if (opcion == 6)
    alcancia1.vaciarAlcancia();
    if (opcion == 7)
    cout<<"La cantidad de monedas de $20 es: "<<alcancia1.getcantidadMonedas20()<<endl;
    if (opcion == 8)
    cout<<"La cantidad de monedas de $50 es: "<<alcancia1.getcantidadMonedas50()<<endl;
    if (opcion == 9)
    cout<<"La cantidad de monedas de $100 es: "<<alcancia1.getcantidadMonedas100()<<endl;
    if (opcion == 10)
    cout<<"La cantidad de monedas de $200 es: "<<alcancia1.getcantidadMonedas200()<<endl;
    if (opcion == 11)
    cout<<"La cantdad de monedas de $500 es: "<<alcancia1.getcantidadMonedas500()<<endl;
    if (opcion == 12)
    cout<<"Cantidad de dinero ahorrado: "<<alcancia1.gettotalDinero()<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Me da un número muy distante de 0 en la primera vez que selecciono la opción 12 o cualquiera de la 7 a la 11 cuando debería dar 0 porque está inicializada en 0 para todo
Luego, después de seleccionar una opción no sé cómo hacer para que vuelva a mostrarme el menú

Muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Saludos**

tiempo no uso c++; veo que en constructor de `Alcancia` lo tengas:

```
Alcancia::Alcancia(int M20, int M50, int M100, int M200, int M500)
{
   /* Inicializar cada valor a Cero */
    cantidadDineroAhorrado=0;
    cantidadMonedas20=0;
    cantidadMonedas50=0;
    cantidadMonedas100=0;
    cantidadMonedas200=0;
    cantidadMonedas500=0;
   /* Segui tu código normal */
   setcantidadMonedas20(M20);
   setcantidadMonedas50(M50);
   setcantidadMonedas100(M100);
   setcantidadMonedas200(M200);
   setcantidadMonedas500(M500);
}
```

> **EDITADO**

Conforme al código que veo en tu planteamiento, el `main` carece de instrucción repetitiva (while, for, foreach,....); lo que ocurre en el caso que veo es lo siguiente:

1. Ejecutas (se inician lo valores en 0 cero); cualquier valor es cero.
2. Seleccionas alguna de del 1 al 5 *(agregas moneda)*
3. El programa termina ejecución
4. Vuelves a ejecutar el programa (todo es inicializado a cero).
5. Seleccionas opción del 7 en adelante te devuelve cero.

Si es algo como los pasos que antes mencione, claro que siempre será cero el resultado, pues no esta ejecutandose el programa hasta que decides finalizarlo.Para ello tendras que agregar una opción 0(cero) o 13 con el cual terminaras de formas como corresponda el bucle (ciclo) que elijas implementar.

Comment: Pero luego cuando en la ejecución del programa agrego una moneda de x tipo y luego le pregunto cuántas hay de ese tipo me continúa arrojando 0